# Xrandr error. Can't add new resolution on Linux

Tags: nvidia, xrandr

When I'm trying to add a new resolution with higher refresh rate(75hz instead of 60hz) Xrandr gives me this error

```
root@Coloruts:~# xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 1920x1080_75.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  39
Current serial number in output stream:  40
```

Before that I got modeline from cvt

```
root@Coloruts:~# cvt 1920 1080 75
# 1920x1080 74.91 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 84.64 kHz; pclk: 220.75 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_75.00"  220.75  1920 2064 2264 2608  1080 1083 1088 1130 -hsync +vsync
```

Then I did that

```
root@Coloruts:~# xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_75.00" 220.75  1920 2064 2264 2608  1080 1083 1088 1130 -hsync +vsync
```

Also I edited xorg.conf file

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ GW2270"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    ModeLine       "1920x1080_75.00" 220.75  1920 2064 2264 2608  1080 1083 1088 1130 -hsync +vsync
EndSection
```

I found these HorizSync and VertRefresh parameters on google for my Benq GW2270H monitor, they seem to be correct. Also I can use even 1920x1080 with 85Hz refresh rate on Windows. I'm using the newest nvidia driver for GTX 950

Comment: In my experience, forcing unsuccessful resolution with xrandr always proved to be caused by xrandr not wanting to set a resolution that is not supported or cannot be used because of hardware limitations. I would suggest you check your hardware really supports it.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure my hardware supports that. As I said, on Windows I can use even 85hz.

That modeline didn't help. Got the same error